Button Masking Holding an Image
I have a navigation bar that has a background color and contains some buttons which are transparent and hold the navigation bar background color
i have another div where it contains an image which navigation bar overlap with
i want when a button is pressed the button becomes transparent(it already is but holding the navigation bar color) and hold the image instead
As the button mask and make that specific part of the div transparent
export default function TouristHomePageNavigation(){
    const [navigation,setNavigation] = useState(1);
    const buttonNames = ["Experiences","Stays","Travel","Shop"];
    return(
        <>
        <div className="flex bg-green-500 justify-center pt-2 z-10 relative px-0">
            {buttonNames.map((buttonName,index) => (
                <NavigationButton index={index+1} navigation={navigation} setNavigation={setNavigation} buttonName={buttonName} />  
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className=" h-1/2 absolute w-full top-0 z-0">
            <img src={HotAirImage} draggable={false} className="w-full h-full object-cover" />
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

function NavigationButton(ButtonProps : ButtonProps){
    return( 
        <Button className={cn("rounded-none rounded-t-md min-w-[10%]", ButtonProps.navigation == ButtonProps.index ? "bg-transparent" : "bg-white text-foreground")} onClick={() => ButtonProps.setNavigation(ButtonProps.index)}> {ButtonProps.buttonName} </Button>
    )
}

